# Hide or remove the Remove button in WP_Customize_Image_Control

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm using the `WP_Customize_Image_Control` function to allow users to upload an image. Once they've uploaded it, I don't want them to remove the image, only to change it.  This is what I want (look ma, no remove button):

[image]

How can I hide or remove the `remove` button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just hide it with CSS. For example:

```
#customize-control-custom_logo .button.remove-button {
    display: none;
}
```

The harder way would be to subclass the image control JS and omit the remove button from the template, but this seems overkill.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the CSS option crossed my mind, but it seemed a little hacky, so thought there might be an official way, like a filter or through the `$args` parameter. I agree that subclassing the image control is way overkill.